# tensorflow installation setup tools requirements error

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, setuptools, tensorboard

> **tensorboard** 1.14.0 has requirement that **setuptools** version should be atleast 41.0.0, but you have **setuptools** 40.8.0 which is
>   incompatible

How should I solve this in anaconda prompt [tensorflow installion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGNl1.png)

I’m setting up a tensorflow installion, and want to support setuptools fully in my system.

Will installing setuptools 41.0.0 or latest will help me or something else has to be done too?
Please help

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading your `setuptools` will solve the problem. Below command can be used to upgrade `setuptools` :

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools==41.0.0
```